# ngGrid not displayed when used with route provider

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-routing, ng-grid

Below is my HTML and the code to do a web service call and display the data in ngGrid. The problem is with the route provider, I'm not being able to show the grid in my separate view, but if I do the exact same code without the route provider,and load just that page, it works perfectly fine.

Since I'm very new to angularJS, any suggestions would be appreciated.I've done lot of research but did not work, at least for me. Please consider this if I have missed related post somewhere. Thanks ahead!

```
 <div>
    <!--Placeholder for views-->
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>

//this is what I have in one of my view for grid.
<div class="gridStyle" data-ng-grid="gridOptions">
</div>

/* display/get/call the JSON data from the web service and bind it to the view */
var app = angular.module('salesApp',['ngGrid']);

app.config (['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
            .when('/sales',
            {
                controller:'salesCtrl',
                templateUrl:'Partials/sales.html'

            })
            .when('/associate',
            {
                controller:'assocCtrl',
                templateUrl:'Partials/associate.html'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo:'/sales'});
}]);

app.controller('salesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('http://some url...')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.sales = data;

            });

    $scope.gridOptions = {data: 'sales',
        columnDefs:[{field:'Region_Num', displayName: 'Region Num'}
            ],
        showGroupPanel: true
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an older post; but I was having the same problem.  It turns out when I defined the app/Moduile; I was not passing ngGrid in as one of the options:

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
```

That is clearly not your problem; as I do see the statement in your code; so this answer is probably for other people who find this question via Google.

Comment: You are right, you do have to pass ngGrid, but I don't understand, why it does not work at all whenever I try to use it with the route provider.